# Animations in sequence

Tags: android, animation, sequence

I want to set colors to my tiles in sequence. 
This function is called in a for-loop, so its called some times in a very short timewindow.

```
            tile.setImage(R.drawable.blue);
```

This is the function:

```
public void setImage(int resId){

    Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), R.animator.fadein);
    startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);

    setImageResource(resId);
}
```

and this is the fadein.xml

```
<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

I want the animation to start only if the animation before it is done. 
So I would like the first image to be drawn the first sec and the second image during the second sec, and so on.

BR

Answer (score 0):

Use [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) especially its method `onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)`

```
fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // CALL next animation
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });`
```